# How to make this VBA so that it concatenates range A2:A200 but pastes in a new cell 15 cells have already been concatenated together?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to alter this VBA so that it concatenates the range of A2:A200 but rather than inputting the result into the specified C1 cell, it will instead go through A2:A16, A17:A31, A32:A46, A47:A61....so on and so forth until A200, and paste each 15 cell range into C1, C2, C3, etc.

Here is my current VBA:

```
Sub vba_concatenate()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As String
    Dim SourceRange As Range

  Set SourceRange = Range("A2:A200")

  For Each Rng In SourceRange
    If LenB(Rng) > 0 Then   'Check if Rng is empty
       If LenB(i) = 0 Then
          i = Rng    'First item
       Else
          i = i & " OR " & Rng  'Append to string
       End If
    Else
       Exit For
    End If
  Next Rng

  Range("C1").Value = Trim(i)

End Sub
```

I tried editing the code but I am not well versed with macros so I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concatenate Groups of Cells

**Don't Count Blanks**

[image]

**Count Blanks**

[image]

```vb
Sub ConcatGroupsOfCells()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Concatenate Groups of Cells"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "C2" ' "C1"
    Const CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT As Long = 3 ' 15
    Const CONCAT_DELIMITER As String = " OR "
    Const COUNT_BLANKS As Boolean = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "All cells are empty!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    Dim scell As Range, sStr As String, dStr As String, n As Long
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        If COUNT_BLANKS Then n = n + 1
        sStr = CStr(scell.Value)
        If Len(sStr) > 0 Then
            If Not IsFound Then IsFound = True
            If Not COUNT_BLANKS Then n = n + 1
            If Len(dStr) = 0 Then
                dStr = sStr
            Else
                dStr = dStr & CONCAT_DELIMITER & sStr
            End If
        End If
        If n = CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT Then
            dcell.Value = dStr
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
            dStr = vbNullString
            n = 0
        End If
    Next scell
    
    If Len(dStr) > 0 Then
        dcell.Value = dStr
    Else
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(-1)
    End If
    
    If Not IsFound Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With dcell
        .Offset(1).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row).Clear
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Groups of " & CONCAT_CELLS_COUNT & " cells concatenated " _
        & "and returned in range """ & DST_FIRST_CELL & ":" _
        & dcell.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Vba_Concatenate()
    
    With Range("A2:A200")
    
        Dim n As Long
            Do
            
                Dim res As String
                res = vbNullString
                
                Dim cel As Range
                    For Each cel In .Offset(n * 15).Resize(15)
                        If Len(WorksheetFunction.Trim(cel.Value2)) > 0 Then
                            res = res & cel.Value2 & " OR "
                        End If
                    Next
                
                    Range("C1").Offset(n).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Left$(res, Len(res) - 3))
                
                    n = n + 1
                
            Loop While n * 15 < .Rows.Count
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```